# ProfileManages webcontrol on person.aspx page in SP2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, moss

I am migrating  **ProfileManages** webcontrol on **person.aspx** page from **MOSS 2007** to **2013**. could you please confirm whether this

```
namespace(Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileManages)
```

is  existing  in  **SharePoint 2013**? Not able to find

Can anyone help? need to add Organizational Hierarchy list to the page.

Answer (score 0):

There is Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.dll in GAC on SharePoint 2013 server installation and it contains class:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileManages
```

Path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal\